# Сократить подпись сообщения OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, цифровая-подпись

Необходимо подписать некоторое короткое сообщение и отправить результат `GET` запросом. Подписываю с помощью команды 
`smime -sign -binary -otform PEM`
Проблема в том, что `smime` включает сертификаты для проверки, в результате чего само исходящее сообщение получается слишком длинным. IE обрезает `GET` строку до 2048 символов, и механизм не работает в IE. Что можно использовать кроме `smime`, чтоб получить более короткую строку? Формат PKCS#7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не включать сертификаты в том же эсмайме, у него есть параметр:

```
smime -sign -nocerts -binary -outform PEM
```

Для ещё большей эффективности я бы всё это дело сжал где-то в таком виде:

```
smime -sign -nocerts -binary -outform DER | xz | base64 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '\n'
```

(получится пригодная к использованию в запросе строка)

Comment: с `-nocerts` строка короче, но все равно длиннее 2048 символов. В любом случае спасибо за отклик, за все это время я уже успел на проблему забить =)